# Is there a module that prints a list like `ls -C`?

Tags: arrays, perl, cpan

Is there a module that prints (or helps me printing) a list whose elements are strings (scalars) in a `ls -C` fashion?

Something like the following imaginary program:

```
use strict; use warnings;

use Unknown::Module;

my $ls = new Unknown::Module (columns => 3);

$ls -> print_ls_C qw(abc def ghi jklmnop q rst uv wxy z);
```

The output should then be something like

```
 abc  jklmnop  uv
 def  q        wxy
 ghi  rst      z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Perl6::Form;
my $cols = shift || 3;
my @list = qw(abc def ghi jklmnop q rst uv wxy z);
print form   q/ {:[{*}[:} / x $cols, ( \@list ) x $cols ;;;
__END__
abc                      jklmnop                  uv
def                      q                        wxy
ghi                      rst                      z
```

This is from example demo_columns , see more examples in https://metacpan.org/source/DCONWAY/Perl6-Form-0.04/demo